# Can any one Know about this error Of CI?

Tags: codeigniter

I had uploaded my project in server. when i give the url in the browser only the index page opens . when i tried to open other pages  i get the following error..

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided
settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

my databse config file is this ...

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'wwwanyth';
$db['default']['password'] = 'wwwanythexport';
$db['default']['database'] = 'wwwanyth_db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Are your details definitely correct?

Comment: try to enter the public IP instead of localhost

Comment: If you're positive the db config is correct, make sure your MySQL database allows connections from the web server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about all mentioned details are correct, then, try changing your database hostname from `localhost` to your DB Server public IP.

If you don't have dedicated hosting, `localhost` usually doesn't work.

You can find the actual address of your database from your control panel.

Answer (score 1):

### A few things:

#### Driver

Are you sure the server has the `mysql` installed. I accidentally did that to a school project once. I was using `oci` for oracle when I really need to use `odbc`. Different driver, same concept. Make sure the server has `mysql`.

#### True LO address

Have you tried instead of `localhost`, the loopback address instead.

```
    $db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

`localhost` may not be set up in the host files (weird but definitely possible). If you have console access, try to ping it (`ping localhost`). If it's a failure, then the reference `localhost` doesn't exist.

#### Server IP

You could try the server's actual IP and hope that `mysql` is listening on that interface.

#### Server port

On that server, is `mysql` running on the default port (3306) or is it on a different one. If it is on a different one, you'll need to specify that:

```
$db['default']['port'] = 1337;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check all the setting again with the password. This error is only throw if the database setting the not proper. Following points needs to check

- Database Name
- User Name
- Password
- Host Name

Answer (score 0):

Set `$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;`. Here **mysql_pconnect()** is disabled, So we are using **mysql_connect()**.